# Live555 on Android

Tags: android, video-streaming, rtsp, rtp, live555

I'm trying to get the RTSP video stream play in my Android App using the build-in Videoview/MediaPlayer, but there're always various problems on different ROMs or different network status(UDP packets blocked), it's really annoying so I want to implement my own rtsp client with the live555 source and GLES and ffmpeg. I can figure out how to use ffmpeg and GLES to show a video, but I'm not familiar with live555.

Are there any compiled version of live555 on Android? or how could I do that myself?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Anybody has successfully ported live555 to android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10821015/anybody-has-successfully-ported-live555-to-android)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I found a [sample code](https://github.com/boltonli/ohbee/tree/master/android/streamer/jni)  from github, it works for me.

Comment: @Bolton could you, possibly, elaborate on how you made that code work? I've been struggling with no success so far.

Comment: @Bolton have been using this same link....bt getting exception because jnix.Pipe missing from the jni folder...can u please hel me in this issue...

Comment: Hey Bolton, could you elaborate a bit more how you make it work?

Comment: @Bolton Would you please explain a little more to how about using thi sample code?!

Answer (score 0):

bad news - I think you won't find any precompiled versions of live555 - only a config-makefile-structure for several platforms - except android.

Since live555 is a pure c++ library you will most likely have problems with directly using the lib in Android.

jens.

Comment: Actually I am using live555 and am able to stream the video. In my case RTSP H264 video. Using Android MediaCodec to stream my packets to SurfaceView.the oly issue is after 3-4 hours, stop getting packets from live555 and need to restart the video