# Live555 +Cygwin + Android NDK

Tags: android, cygwin, android-ndk, live555

I am trying to compile live555 for android.  My aim is to use it for capturing data from camera and multicasting it.  But I am not able to compile the live555 code for android environment using windows + NDK + Cygwin.

Has any one able to port live555 on android with above environment?  What are the other options availble for me for my problem listed above other then live 555?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Anybody has successfully ported live555 to android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10821015/anybody-has-successfully-ported-live555-to-android)

Answer (score 2):

Check out

[Live555 on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469533/live555-on-android)

This demonstrates an android project which uses Live555

Comment: In the link shared above the author is trying to play the video on android hardware.But my problem is i want this streamer to run on android hardware

Comment: I haven't run the program yet, but there's code for streaming also in it. https://github.com/boltonli/ohbee/blob/master/android/streamer/jni/streamer/src/streamer.cpp
Check line 128, after starting streaming, a rtsp URL is given.

Comment: Hi thanks,i will have a look at it.Can you tell me wht other options available in opensource to multicast media from android using wifi ?

Comment: Hi Abhiheet did you had any luck in compiling live555 on android. That code doesnt seem to work.

Comment: I haven't looked at it. Will look today and tell you.

Comment: Hmm.. haven't got time till now. Will check today eve.

Comment: Maybe this link is helpful: http://dbmibu.blogspot.com/2011/06/cross-compile-live555-streaming-media.html