# Anybody has successfully ported live555 to android?

Tags: android, live555

I've been trying to build `live555` according to this guide:

https://github.com/boltonli/ohbee/tree/master/android/streamer/jni

as well as using some other guides, all to no avail.

If someone has succeeded in porting `live555` to android can you, please, tell me how I can do so?

Comment: what is problem with the build?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Live555 on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469533/live555-on-android)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I successfully built the project as follows:

```
git clone https://github.com/boltonli/ohbee.git
cd ohbee/android/streamer
android update project --path . --name "streamer" --target "android-15"
cp lib/jnix.jar libs/ # This is the only trick
ant debug
```

The jar was in the `lib/` directory rather than `libs/`.

If that doesn't resolve the issue you were or are having, you'll have to be more specific and share the steps you've taken and what problems you're encountering.

Comment: What is different between using software library to decoding and using native hardware decoding library that is in android source?

Comment: What do you mean by "android update project --path . --name "streamer" --target "android-15" ?!!! I got not found command!

Comment: @Mr.Hyde You'll have to install and set up the Android SDK.

Comment: @Darshan-JosiahBarber I did and added to Environment Variables as ANDROID_HOME

Comment: For Windows:
I had to run `android update project --path . --name "streamer" --target "android-15` from **command prompt**.
And the rest from in **Git Bash**
[Android Path Configuration that was used](http://imgur.com/MF4PZDx)

Answer (score 2):

To compile Live555 streaming media for ARM/Linux try following steps:

```
> cd live
> ./genMakefiles armlinux
> make
```

Pre-built binary package:

live.2011.06.16-dev-armlinux.tar.bz2

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11026883/6314232) worked for me and I was able to build the project in Android Studio:

However, at runtime, I was getting a java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError at the line in MainActivity.java:
System.loadLibrary("jnix");

libjnix.so is missing from ohbee/android/streamer/*, but the armeabi binary is in ohbee/android/streamer2/libs/armeabi. When I copied this into my src/main/jniLibs/armeabi, I was able to run the application on Samsung Galaxy Note S3. It streams the camera into an RTPSink instance with a dummy address.

Obviously, targets which are not armeabi will not work (so virtual devices don't work), and I haven't been able to find the source for the jnix libs (only the headers).

Comment: Does it create an RTSP server? Can you watch the stream with VLC?

Comment: My build was just a client and I never tried creating a server. Only had a few days to spend before the project was shelved, but was definitely seeing a good flow through to the RTPSink.